# How to force CMAKE in building SWIG module in release mode

Tags: cmake, swig

Is there a way to forcefully set the release mode of swig modules in cmake to build in release mode no matter what the actual build type is?

I am trying to build a python module using swig autogenerated code, and it complains of a python debug library when I build my application in debug mode.

I am not interested in debugging python module related code, so I am fine with not building the swig autogenerated python modules in debug mode.

Here is what I have in my cmakelists.txt file:

```
set_source_files_properties(abstract.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS on)
swig_add_module(${PROJECT_NAME} python abstract.i)
swig_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the real issue is that MSVC produces link error, due to the missing "python_d.lib"
Just insert into the header of SWIG interface (your *.i) files:

```
%begin %{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define SWIG_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_NO_DEBUG
#endif
%}
```

... and remove

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
... 
#endif
```

when the issue is generic, not MSVC related only

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about wrapping your code snippet in

```
set(CMAKE_TMP_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
```

and

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_TMP_BUILD_TYPE})
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell CMake not to include a project in the default build of a certain configuration. For example, for a Python module (with the underscore added to the target by SWIG):

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(_${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_DEBUG True)
```